# Why `lapply` returns result of assignment automatically?

Tags: r, return-value, variable-assignment, lapply

```
q <- lapply(1:3, function(x) x ** 2)
## returns nothing, because it is an assignment

# however, how you explain this?:

> lapply(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:11), function(v) q <- lapply(v, function(x) x ** 2))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 9


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 16

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 25

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 36


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 49

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 64

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 81


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 100

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 121

# while this gives the same but is logical (q is stated as return value).
> lapply(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:11), function(v) {q <- lapply(v, function(x) x ** 2);q})
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 9


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 16

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 25

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 36


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 49

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 64

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 81


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 100

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 121
```

why in the second expression, although the inner `lapply` is just assigned to `q` but `q` not called at end of function, the value of the assignment
is returned to the outer `lapply` and thus collected?
Please, anybody has an explanation for this phenomenon?

It also works with `=`

```
lapply(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:11), function(v) q = lapply(c(v), function(x) x ** 2))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 9


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 16

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 25

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 36


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 49

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 64

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 81


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 100

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 121
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the *return value* of an *assignment operation*. The assignment operator `<-` not only writes a value to a variable in the calling environment, it actually invisibly returns the assigned value itself to the caller.

Remember all operations in R are actually functions. When you do

```r
x <- 3
```

You are actually doing

```
`<-`(x, 3)
```

Which not only creates the symbol "x" in the calling environment and assigns the value 3 to that symbol, but *invisibly returns the value 3 to the caller*. To see this, consider:

```
y <- 2
y
#> [1] 2

y <- `<-`(x, 3)
y
#> [1] 3
```

Or equivalently,

```
y <- (x <- 4)
y
#> [1] 4
```

And in fact, because of R's order of evaluation, we can even do:

```
y <- x <- 5
y
#> [1] 5
```

Which is a neat way of setting multiple variables to the same value on the same line.

Now consider the lambda function you use inside your `lapply`:

```r
function(v) q <- lapply(v, function(x) x ** 2)
```

Look what happens when we consider this function as a stand-alone:

```r
func <- function(v) q <- lapply(v, function(x) x ** 2)

func(1:3)
```

As predicted, nothing happens. But what happens when we do:

```r
a <- func(1:3)
```

If func(1:3) doesn't return anything, then presumably `a` should be empty now.

But it isn't...

```r
 a
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 4
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 9
```

Because the value of assignation was returned to the caller invisibly, we were able to assign it to a value in the calling scope. Therefore, doing

```r
lapply(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:11), function(v) q <- lapply(v, function(x) x ** 2))
```

assigns the value of your inner function applied to all the list elements to a new list. This list is *not* returned invisibly, but just returned as normal.

So this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I didn't know that `<-` silently returns the value! `print(q <- 3)` indeed prints `3`.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim exactly!

Comment: This is a great answer!  Everyone should upvote this.  I started to write this and decided it was going to take too long to explain.  Well done @AllanCameron!